# Wagtail, CORS and Django-Cors-Headers. How to enable CORS so that AXIOS can get to the endpoints

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, wagtail, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to enable the Wagtail API so I can do some exciting stuff in Vue. However, I've followed all the instructions for enabling the API in Wagtail and there is no mention of CORS. Well, it's less than a paragraph.

I use Django-Cors-Headers on all my projects and set it up as I normally would, but for some reason, the API still won't allow access.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to allow a CORS connection to the Wagtail API endpoints using DJANGO-CORS-HEADERS?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/) might be helpful. I can't talk for wagtail since I'm not using it in this particular project, but with the help of that and looking at the syntax for django 2's middleware, I came up with this:

```
class CorsMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self,get_response):
        self.get_response=get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        print('test')
        response=self.get_response(request)
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        return response
```

Also make sure that when you're inserting the middleware into your settings.py, that you include the filename as well as the module name and component name, i.e. 'AppName.FileName.CorsMiddleware' instead of what's suggested on the linked site to put 'AppName.CorsMiddleware'. Maybe typo maybe old syntax ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

(The * might be a slight security risk, but i only needed it in development so i wasn't rly putting too much thought into it)

Comment: This has been really helpful. Thank you.